# Behavior of <enter> key in JEditorPane (with HtmlEditorKit)

Tags: java, swing, newline, paragraph, htmleditorkit

If I put the cursor in the middle of `<p>A line of text</p>` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> I get

```
<p>A line</p>
<p>of text</p>
```

This is on my Linux dev machine.

When I run the same application on a Windows machine, I get

```
<p>A line
of text</p>
```

i.e. a `\n` inserted instead of creating an extra `<p>` element. Since `\n` is just rendered as a space in HTML, <kbd>enter</kbd> basically doesn't work when I'm on Windows.

**Question:** How do I force the *insert `<p>`* behavior upon <kbd>enter</kbd> on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) the Enter key is mapped to the "insert-break" Acton.

In Windows this Action is defined in the `DefaultEditorKit`:

```
public static class InsertBreakAction extends TextAction {

    /**
     * Creates this object with the appropriate identifier.
     */
    public InsertBreakAction() {
        super(insertBreakAction);
    }

    /**
     * The operation to perform when this action is triggered.
     *
     * @param e the action event
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JTextComponent target = getTextComponent(e);
        if (target != null) {
            if ((! target.isEditable()) || (! target.isEnabled())) {
                UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(target);
                return;
            }
            target.replaceSelection("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and simply adds "\n" as you suggest.

If you have different behaviour on Linux then I would guess a custom Action is added to the HTMLEditorKit to insert the paragraph tag.

So I would suggest you need to find that Action and then add it to the HTMLEditorKit in the Windows platform.

Comment: This was what my debugging revealed as well. In fact it actually uses `StyledInsertBreakAction` in `StyledEditorKit`. It would surprise me different actions are used in different machines. I would suspect it has something to do with system line endings. I've tried to reproduce it on a different Windows machine without luck however :-/